# Save data in Users/NAME/Roaming/AppData?

Tags: c#

Pretty new to C# but not new in programming in generally.

I'm still trying to figure out how best practice is when a program has to save inputs from the user.

Let's say that I have a very simple Visual C# Windows Form program containing:

- one textfield
- one button "Add button"
- one listbox

User can enter text in the textfield, and when pressing the Add button the program is saving the entered the text (somewhere and somehow).
And the saved text is showed in the listbox.
(Let's say a user does this 10 times. So the listbox helds 10 entrys with text from the textfield).

HOW is the best practice to do this? XML? txt file?
Having a database running on the computer is not an option. It has to work on *every* WinXP/Win7 machine and it can't have any dependencies. Just install the program and it has to work.

Hope that you understand my questions.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: mmm.. xml or txt storing data is a sort of database ;).. anyway, access is not an option?

Comment: In fact, the tag C# doesn't look right to me. OP is asking general advice, that goes beyond C#...

Comment: Database is fine - IF it doesn't is required as a standalone.
Eg: The user doesn't have to have a database server installed on their computer. 

Sorry for the tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an XML file or a SQL CE database in

```
Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
    @"Your App Name\Data.xml"
)
```

Comment: But is it easy to sort entrys from a XML file?
Let's say the program have:

unique id auto increment
name
something else
something else again


Is it easy to sort by "something else" when storing via XML? Or is it best with a database?

Comment: That depends on exactly want you want to do.  SQL CE is likely to be easier, and does not require installation.

Comment: Oh, so it is just by using a "local database" in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: I feel so stupid :(

SQL CE was exactly what I was looking for :)

Any help on how to make it with an installation wizard which uses /Users/NAME/(etc..) as storing data and preferences?

Comment: @user1281991: Why do you want an installation wizard? I'm not sure what you're asking..

Comment: I don't like the "Clickonce"-thingy. The typical installation wizard (that almost every Win program uses) looks much better IMO.

But maybe it is normal practice when coding visual C# to use the Clickonce? Eg. when using Clickonce where is my program installed? Can't even find it LOL. Except from the Start menu

Comment: You can use whatever you want.