# Keeping the programs' data after exit

Tags: c#, .net

I made a C# program for myself in which I can select and add different things I have to do the next day (a simple schedule).

I have it all sorted out but one thing that I do not know how to begin scripting it. I want to be able to keep the schedule after exit. For example: `Tomorrow I have to do the following : (my To-Do list ) etc.` . Now I close the program ,and if I re-open it it is all gone.

My question is, how do I keep it after exit?

Comment: you need a database for that.

flatfile or sqlite or mysql etc

you could also serialize your list to a file and deserialize it when you open your app.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3032492/3970411

Comment: @gimpycpu I already have a button which exports the whole schedule in a `.txt` filetype. I did it just for testing and also keeping backups. Can I use that export file as a "Import"? Also can I add all this under a `_Mouseclick`? Thank you!

Comment: @dotctor sorry if it is a duplicate. I searched in the website as " Keep data" and i suppose i did not see the "Save settings " link

Comment: The application settings are different from stored data. I wouldn't use the app settings if I was you.

Comment: @PatrickHofman So how do you recommend I should proceed ?

Comment: @Maiels: See the options in my answer.

Comment: On where you might like to save your files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808999/save-data-in-users-name-roaming-appdata

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use one of the following options:

- A database, like [SQL Lite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263243.aspx), [LocalDB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272703%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) or others;
- [Save the data in a text file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx) and read and write it yourself;
- Use the built-in .NET [XML serializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).